# sonarqube analysis is very slow and taking morethan 2 hours to generate report

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, devops, sonarqube-scan

We are using sonarqube for analysis. when we do scan first time from starting tag(tail) to particular tag it is working properly.(generating report within 15-20 minutes). But when we run the analysis from the tail to head again top of the previous analysis  to generate report it is taking hell out of time (like more than 3 hours).

Let us know how to reduce this time.

Sonarqube version-6.75-LTS
This is my sonar-project.properties

```
sonar.projectKey=Platform_UI
sonar.projectName=Platform_UI
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.sources=UI_Services
sonar.java.binaries=UI_Services
sonar.scm.enabled=true
sonar.scm.url=scm:ssh://repository@sbchdks.com/home/repository/PLAT_6
```

Comment: Could you compare ram, disk and others metrics between 15min and 3hours execution?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am very much new to sonarqube. Let me know what are other metrics. we are using 8gb ram and 40 gb disk. I checked it ram and disk space is there

Comment: Did you have a look at the SonarQube log files what was taking so long?

Comment: Sainath, I mean a comparison at operative system level. For instance, copy a file of 10GB is very slow compare to a 10mb file. Just exec a `top` command when you run SonarQube for tag and the same for head. Also a good comparation is check the SonarQube log for tag and head. In the log you could detect for instance that, in the line number 50, for tag takes 1 min, but for head takes 1h.

Comment: Go to your sonar project and find the Administration menu tab. You will find logs at Administration --> Background tasks .  Fetch both logs and compare where is stuck, these logs are generally verbose.